# Neo4j: using distance() function to determine distance between houses

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working with data from a csv file which contains three columns of data: `house`, `houseLong`, `houseLat` where `house` is the unique number of the house, `houseLong` is the longitude of the location of the house and `houseLat` is the latitude of the location of the house.

Sample data as follows:

Row 1 `1, 22.6932, 100.5347`

Row 2 `2, 25.6589, 98.5679`

Row 3 `3, 33.1674, 66.3287`

All the way to the last row

Row 100 `100, 37.6532, 95.3567`

I've imported all of this data into Neo4j - the nodes are labelled `House`.

For each house, I'm trying to work out the distance between it and the other houses.

So for house 1, I'm trying to get the distance from house 1 to house 2, house 1 to house 3, and so on until house 100.

For house 2, I'm trying to get the distance from house 2 to house 1, house 2 to house 3, and so on until house 100.

I'm unsure of the best way to implement this query. Right now all I can do is this:

```
MATCH (h1: House {house: 1}), (h2: House {house: 2})
WITH point({longitude: h1.houseLong, latitude: h1.houseLat}) AS point1, point({longitude: h2.houseLong, latitude: h2.houseLat}) AS point2
RETURN round(distance(point1, point2)) AS Distance
```

The above query gives me the distance between house 1 and house 2, but I'm unsure of how to scale this for every house in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the distances, ordered by `house` values:

```
MATCH (h1: House), (h2: House)
WHERE h1 <> h2
RETURN
  h1, h2,
  round(distance(
    point({longitude: h1.houseLong, latitude: h1.houseLat}),
    point({longitude: h2.houseLong, latitude: h2.houseLat}))) AS dist
ORDER BY h1.house, h2.house
```

NOTE: Every pair of houses will be represented twice (in reverse order), which is apparently what you wanted.